# Gateway page system

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to alter the way we currently provide a gateway page system within our CMS. What i mean by gateway page is mapping a non-existent URL to a page through a rewrite rule in the .htaccess, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^foobar$ page.php?mode=bar&method=foo&id=1
```

This allows people to create short links to CMS pages for magazine adverts etc. The problem with this method is that it relies on access to the .htaccess. I would prefer a method that sits at code level but it occurs to me that - without a rewrite rule - a 404 error will be called. Is there any way to prevent this or work around this?

Comment: any problem with your .htaccess? Why is it a problem to rely on it?

Comment: its a problem if new redirects need to be added dynamically and incorrect syntax causes 500 errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rewritemap within your htaccess. What this does is references an external file/script, passing it the incoming uri and getting back the rewritten uri.

In your .htaccess

```
RewriteMap shorts prg:/path/to/map.php
```

In your php file map.php

```
#!/path/to/php
$keyboard = fopen("php://stdin","r"); // get data from stdin
while (1) {
    $line = trim(fgets($keyboard));
    // fetch rewrite for line and echo out
}
```

The php file is passed the short url and returns - based on your logic - the full url

Comment: I do like this option, i assume though that it still falls down where any .htaccess rule falls down - incorrect syntax = 500 error?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to run a test. You could try returning null, see how the rule handles that. Sorry, I'm a bit rusty!